# HTTP 330 error on PHP deprecation errors

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

For some reason, I get a HTTP 330 error whenever a PHP error is printed. This didn't use to happen, but since we had to restore our PHP application from a backup due to a server failure, it does. During that restoration, we switched over from using Apache to nginx + fastcgi. However, I'm also running the application locally, and I'm noticing the same issue on Apache, but only when using php 5.3.X. The application used to run on 5.2.11.

Has anyone encountered anything like this before? The only thing that googling has brought up is that maybe the PHP errors are sent using one encoding, and the rest of the content is sent gzipped, but I have no idea how to fix that - if it even is the problem.

Please ask if you need any more information. I'm not quite sure what information I could provide you with that would be helpful.

Comment: what error messages do you get? Check your nginx and php error log. Also, did you change the PHP version or changed error reporting level?

Comment: Problem is, I can't see the error messages, because they're just sent as a 330 error. However, I know that they're simply deprecation warnings.

Comment: there is no HTTP 330 Status Code though: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: Sorry, you're right. It's not an HTTP error. It's a browser specific thing. This: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=3388bd392b939f43&hl=en

Comment: I've found that the error occurs in PHP 5.3.X, but not in 5.2.X.

Comment: Do you have something like mod_security installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enabling zlib compression in php.ini (`zlib.output_compression = On`) and then removing any `ob_start("ob_gzhandler");` from the scripts seems to have solved the problem.