# Error 330 net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED with Minify on first load

Tags: php, css, gzip, minify, zlib

Minify is a PHP5 minifier for JS and CSS files : http://code.google.com/p/minify/

When I modify a CSS file then reload the page via Google Chrome, on the first load, I have this error :

```
Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED): Unknown error
```

It's only on the first load of the page after the CSS modification. If I reload after, there is no error.

I believed it was a problem with Zlib like on : [HTTP 330 error on PHP deprecation errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024981/http-330-error-on-php-deprecation-errors) but Zlib is activated on my server.

The error is not happening when Minify is in debug mode (so when it only merge file and doesn't modify nor compress content)

Comment: now it has version "Minify 2.1.7".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in 2.1.5. I had the same problem you described, but only in 2.1.5 so I downgraded to 2.1.3 and it works.

Here is the download link to 2.1.3:

http://code.google.com/p/minify/downloads/detail?name=minify_2.1.3.zip

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the file (css) you've upload has a different encoding (not UTF-8). The first time you reload the page it kills the process when it can't get the compressed files. Once you change the working encoding to UTF-8 and upload the file you might not get the error.

The only thing I couldn't figure out is why the minify process is correct after the second reload....